# SQL Syntax To Aggregate Records Based on Field Criteria and Output Total Record Counts

Tags: sql, syntax, teradata

The SQL query returns table results that look like this:

[image]

The SQL I am currently running to generate this table is listed below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ld.LOAD_ID, lf.ACTUAL_DELIVERY_TS, ld.ORIG_LOC_ID, 
    fsd.PO_TYPE_CODE, fsf.CASE_QTY, 
    CASE 
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6903, 6909, 6912, 7100, 7101, 7183, 7184, 7837, 7840, 7976) 
          THEN 'Centerpoint'
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6061, 6088, 6060, 7042, 7078, 7085, 7086, 7084, 7089, 7093, 7094, 4892, 7628) 
          THEN 'Imports'
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (8092, 8098, 9153, 9193, 9195, 9196) 
          THEN 'Returns'
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6005, 6007, 6008, 6014, 6022, 6029, 6041) 
          THEN 'Fashion'
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (7006, 7356, 6280, 8240, 8103, 7853, 7005) 
          THEN 'eCom'
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6006, 6009, 6010, 6011, 6012, 6016, 6017, 6018, 6019, 6020, 6021, 6023, 6024, 6025, 6026, 6027, 6030, 6031, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6039, 6040, 6043, 6048, 6054, 6066, 6068, 6069, 6070, 6080, 6092, 6094, 7026, 7033, 7034, 7035, 7036, 7038, 7039, 7045) 
          THEN 'Regional'
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6042, 6047, 6055, 6056, 6057, 6059, 6062, 6064, 6065, 6071, 6072, 6073, 6074, 6077, 6082, 6083, 6084, 6085, 6090, 6091, 6095, 6096, 6097, 6099, 7010, 7012, 7013, 7014, 7015, 7016, 7017, 7018, 7019, 7021, 7023, 7024, 7025, 7030, 7047, 7048, 7053, 7055, 7068, 7070, 7077, 7079) 
          THEN 'Grocery'
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_TYPE_CODE IN ('VNDR') 
          THEN 'VNDR'
       WHEN ORIG_LOC_TYPE_CODE IN ('STORE') 
          THEN 'STORE'
    END AS LOADORIG, 
    CASE
       WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE IN (23, 33, 3, 53, 45, 73, 93) THEN 'DA'
       WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE IN (20, 22, 28, 29, 40, 42, 50, 83) THEN 'SS'
       WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE IN (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19) THEN 'Fashion'
       WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE IN (43) THEN 'XDOCK'
    END AS CHANNEL, 
    ld.DEST_LOC_ID
FROM 
    us_trans_dm_vm.LOAD_DIM ld, 
    us_trans_dm_vm.LOAD_FACT lf, 
    us_trans_dm_vm.FREIGHT_SHIPMENT_FACT fsf, 
    us_trans_dm_vm.FREIGHT_SHIPMENT_DIM fsd
WHERE 
    ld.LOAD_SK_ID = lf.LOAD_SK_ID
    AND lf.LOAD_SK_ID = fsf.LOAD_SK_ID
    AND fsf.SHIPMENT_SK_ID = fsd.SHIPMENT_SK_ID
    AND fsd.CURRENT_IND = 'Y'
    AND ld.CURRENT_IND = 'Y'
    AND ld.DEST_LOC_ID IN (6006, 6009, 6010, 6011, 6012, 6016, 6017, 6018, 6019, 6020, 6021, 6023, 6024, 6025, 6026, 6027, 6030, 6031, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6039, 6040, 6043, 6048, 6054, 6066, 6068, 6069, 6070, 6080, 6092, 6094, 7026, 7033, 7034, 7035, 7036, 7038, 7039, 7045)
    AND lf.ACTUAL_DELIVERY_TS BETWEEN '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-07-31 23:59:59'
```

The LOAD_ID is the unique record identifier and each LOAD_ID has different PO types and case counts associated with them. I am trying to find a way to aggregate LOAD_ID rows based on some criteria around the PO type and Case Counts:

For example - If PO_TYPE_CODE 20 has CASE_QTY greater than 50% of the total CASE_QTY associated with that LOAD_ID then Count LOAD_ID 30604179 as "TEST"

If PO_TYPE_CODE 33 has CASE_QTY greater than 25% of the total CASE_QTY associated with that LOAD_ID then Count LOAD_ID 30604179 as "TEST 2"

***Desired Output:***

Please any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!!

[image]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to get at this. Something like:

```
 CASE 
    WHEN POT_TYPE_CODE = 20 AND Cast(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(4,2)/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(4,2)) OVER (PARTITION BY LOAD_ID) > .5 
        THEN 'Test' 
    WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE = 33 AND Cast(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(4,2)/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(4,2)) OVER (PARTITION BY LOAD_ID) > .25 
        THEN 'Test 2' 
    END as my_new_field
```

That window function `Sum(Case_QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY LOAD_ID)` will sum up all of the rows in your intermediate result set for that load_id and return the result. Dividing into it the current records `case_qty` gives you the percentage you can test on.

Also, I'm casting the case_qty to decimal to insure that the result of the division is decimal. Otherwise it may round to integer... Can't remember how that would work out, so it may be unnecessary.

Comment: I am getting a 3706 error when running this (expected something between ')' and '/'). I have tried adjusting the parenthesis on these WHEN statements but have no luck. Any ideas on syntax here? I am not familiar with the partition syntax. Otherwise I think it is going to work great

Comment: Looks like I didn't put an ending parentheses on that first Cast. That's the only thing I see that's off. I'm on mobile now so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you'll need, if your criteria is always based on the total CASE_QTY associated with the LOAD_ID, is that result joined in so you can compare each value, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ld.LOAD_ID, ... fsf.CASE_QTY, 100.00 * CASE_QTY/sum_caseQty AS loadCaseQtyPct,
    ...
FROM 
    us_trans_dm_vm.LOAD_DIM ld INNER JOIN
    us_trans_dm_vm.LOAD_FACT lf ON
        ld.LOAD_SK_ID = lf.LOAD_SK_ID INNER JOIN
    us_trans_dm_vm.FREIGHT_SHIPMENT_FACT fsf ON
     lf.LOAD_SK_ID = fsf.LOAD_SK_ID INNER JOIN  
    us_trans_dm_vm.FREIGHT_SHIPMENT_DIM fsd ON
     fsf.SHIPMENT_SK_ID = fsd.SHIPMENT_SK_ID INNER JOIN
     (SELECT
     loadid, SUM(case_qty) AS sum_caseQty
     FROM
     us_trans_dm_vm.LOAD_DIM
     GROUP BY 1) cq ON
     ld.loadid = cq.loadid
WHERE 
     fsd.CURRENT_IND = 'Y'
    AND ld.CURRENT_IND = 'Y'
    AND ld.DEST_LOC_ID IN (6006, 6009, 6010, 6011, 6012, 6016, 6017, 6018, 6019, 6020, 6021, 6023, 6024, 6025, 6026, 6027, 6030, 6031, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6039, 6040, 6043, 6048, 6054, 6066, 6068, 6069, 6070, 6080, 6092, 6094, 7026, 7033, 7034, 7035, 7036, 7038, 7039, 7045)
    AND lf.ACTUAL_DELIVERY_TS BETWEEN '2016-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-07-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

@JNevill

I have adjusted the window functions based on my needed output. I am no longer needing to approach the problem with the 50%/25% criteria mentioned above. Instead I use the window function to compute the Case_QTY percentage for each row compared to the Case_Qty for the overall Load_ID. I am now getting results like the image below.

[image]

Using this SQL:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT ld.LOAD_ID,lf.ACTUAL_DELIVERY_TS,ld.ORIG_LOC_ID,fsd.PO_TYPE_CODE,fsf.CASE_QTY,

CASE 
WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6903,6909,6912,7100,7101,7183,7184,7837,7840,7976) THEN 'Centerpoint'
WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6061,6088,6060,7042,7078,7085,7086,7084,7089,7093,7094,4892,7628) THEN 'Imports'
WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (8092,8098,9153,9193,9195,9196) THEN 'Returns'
WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6005,6007,6008,6014,6022,6029,6041) THEN 'Fashion'
WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (7006,7356,6280,8240,8103,7853,7005) THEN 'eCom'
WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6006, 6009, 6010, 6011, 6012, 6016, 6017, 6018, 6019, 6020, 6021, 6023, 6024, 6025, 6026, 6027, 6030, 6031, 6035, 6036, 6037, 6038, 6039, 6040, 6043, 6048, 6054, 6066, 6068, 6069, 6070, 6080, 6092, 6094, 7026, 7033, 7034, 7035, 7036, 7038, 7039, 7045) THEN 'Regional'
WHEN ORIG_LOC_ID IN (6042, 6047, 6055, 6056, 6057, 6059, 6062, 6064, 6065, 6071, 6072, 6073, 6074, 6077, 6082, 6083, 6084, 6085, 6090, 6091, 6095, 6096, 6097, 6099, 7010, 7012, 7013, 7014, 7015, 7016, 7017, 7018, 7019, 7021, 7023, 7024, 7025, 7030, 7047, 7048, 7053, 7055, 7068, 7070, 7077, 7079) THEN 'Grocery'
WHEN ORIG_LOC_TYPE_CODE IN ('VNDR') THEN 'VNDR'
WHEN ORIG_LOC_TYPE_CODE IN ('STORE') THEN 'STORE'
END AS LOADORIG, 

CASE
WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE IN (23,33,3,53,45,73,93) THEN 'DA'
WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE IN (20,22,28,29,40,42,50,83) THEN 'SS'
WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE IN (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19) THEN 'Fashion'
WHEN PO_TYPE_CODE IN (43) THEN 'XDOCK'
END AS CHANNEL,


CASE 
WHEN Channel = 'DA' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID)
WHEN Channel = 'SS' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID)
END AS New_Column,

ld.DEST_LOC_ID

FROM us_trans_dm_vm.LOAD_DIM ld,
             us_trans_dm_vm.LOAD_FACT lf,
             us_trans_dm_vm.FREIGHT_SHIPMENT_FACT fsf,
             us_trans_dm_vm.FREIGHT_SHIPMENT_DIM fsd

WHERE ld.LOAD_SK_ID = lf.LOAD_SK_ID
AND lf.LOAD_SK_ID = fsf.LOAD_SK_ID
AND fsf.SHIPMENT_SK_ID = fsd.SHIPMENT_SK_ID
AND fsd.CURRENT_IND = 'Y'
AND ld.CURRENT_IND = 'Y'
AND ld.DEST_LOC_ID IN (6006)
AND lf.ACTUAL_DELIVERY_TS BETWEEN '2016-07-20 00:00:00' AND '2016-07-31 23:59:59'

GROUP BY ld.LOAD_ID,lf.ACTUAL_DELIVERY_TS,ld.ORIG_L
```

As you can see, the "New Column" is showing the correct percentages for each Load_Id that all sum to 100%. Now I would like to roll up all of the unique Load_ID by their channel and percenatges.

Example:

[image]

I have been trying to use something like:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Channel = 'DA' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) TotalDACases,
SUM(CASE WHEN Channel = 'SS' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) TotalStapleCases,
```

Or:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Channel = 'DA' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID) END) Test,
SUM (CASE WHEN Channel = 'SS' THEN  CAST (CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,0))/SUM(CAST(CASE_QTY AS DECIMAL(38,2))) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.LOAD_ID) END) Test2,
```

But I am getting an error ("Ordered Analytical Functions can not be nested") and am thinking this is related to me having nested sum functions.

Any thoughts would be great!

Comment: That can't be nested inside of a group by. The reason for this is that they are calculating on top of the result set that is returned by the initial aggregation. Instead you'll have to do the initial big query you have above, and then stick that beast in a subquery and do your further aggregation outside of it. Also, since this is more of a new question, it would be best to stick this in a fresh question on SO being that this here isn't an "Answer".